# Are there other airport worth considering if you are flying to Basel/Mulhouse?

Tags: air-travel, airports, switzerland, basel, bsl

I need to fly to Basel (CH) soon. I have checked fares to Basel/Mulhouse from Brussels. The fares are ridiculous expensive (>900 Euro for an 1 hour flight). I can take the night train, but before considering that I was wondering if there are other airports I could use when I need to be in Basel?

Comment: do you plan to have a car while you're there?

Comment: Have you considered taking a train to Amsterdam and flying to Basel? Both KLM and Easyjet have flights.

Comment: @Gilles Yes. Given the poor train connections in Belgium, Amsterdam from Antwerp is almost always the better option over Brussels. If train connection permit that is. Flights to Basel from Amsterdam leave at 10.00. The train arrivals at Schiphol are then to tight. With the slightest delay you miss your flight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily fly to Zurich. The connections from Brussels to Zurich are way better than the connections from Brussels to Basel. And from Zurich you're in less than a hour in Basel when you take the train. The prices for that train travel start around 15 Swiss franks. The SBB (Swiss national train carrier) has an [understandable website](http://www.sbb.ch/home.html). I found flights for around 300 euros for next week (with [Swiss](http://www.swiss.ch))

You could also fly over Geneva to Zurich which is cheaper (around 200 euro). Then I would think about only take the first leg of the flight, leave the plane in Geneva and take the train. But this really depends on the actual date and time you're going to fly.

You could also fly to Geneva, but this is a little bit further away from Basel. The train takes [almost 3 hours](http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/query.exe/dn?seqnr=1&ident=kf.030933190.1326408541&HWAI=JS!ajax=yes!&HWAI=CONNECTION%24C0-3!id=C0-3!HwaiConId=C0-3!HwaiDetailStatus=details!HwaiConnectionNumber=4!HwaiMoreDetailStatus=none!HwaiAdditionalInformation=none!;~CONNECTION%24C0-3!HwaiMapStatus=UNDEFINED!HwaiMapNumber=UNDEFINED!HwaiMapSlider=UNDEFINED!;).

There are also other airports nearby which may be useful (even if I doubt it). This are particularly Friedrichshafen and Altenrhein.

Answer (score 4):

I would look at flying to Zurich and [taking a train](http://traintickets.myswitzerland.com/rail-tickets-passes/?WT.mc_id=google.myswitzerland+rail+tickets.cpc)

Bern might be another option but may not be as good.  Personally I'd drive but that may be US traveler talking.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would recommend Bern. It is a very small airport and has definitively not direct connection to Brussels.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either but it's a possible destination.  The others are further away.